# Changing oil filter after changing oil

Tags: motorcycle, oil-filter, apache-rtr

Recently I changed engine oil for my motorcycle. The oil filter was not in the service station so I am running it with the old one itself. If I want to change the oil filter is it required to drain the entire oil from the engine or can I just replace it without removing oil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing the filter without draining the oil is almost guaranteed to be very, very messy no matter where the filter's placed. You can re-use the oil as it's fresh, just drain it into a clean container, replace the filter and pour it back in.

Comment: Will it give any performance drawbacks? Or is it fine to continue with the old filter till I replace oil.

Comment: You need to replace the filter as they have a limited life. Once the filter gets full of contaminants it cannot keep your oil clean and it canl lead to longer term problems.

Comment: the Kawasaki KLR 650 2008 repair manual (Clymer) recommends changing the oil filter at least every other oil change, as far as I remember. It's cleaner if you change each time, but delaying this operation might be fine too depending on bike -- unless the oil had visible signs that the filter was failing.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on where the filter is, if all the oil drains out when you remove the filter then add new oil , if not then you need to top-up by the amount lost in the filter.

If you specify make, year, model and engine you might get a more precise answer.

Comment: It's apache rtr, oil filter is at the side of the engine slightly above. But I don't want to take risk of oil leakage as I have replaced it in last week itself.

Comment: You can re-use the oil, just drain it into a clean container, then replace the filter, then pour it back in.